# Firebase Cloud Messaging Error

Tags: android, firebase, runtime-error, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebaseui

I am trying to implement the Firebase Cloud messaging to my Application. But I always get this error :

> No static methetNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzx; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx' appears in /data/app/zockerbros.com.chatapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes15.dex)

Build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Hi. Could you post your build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely use outdated version of the Firebase as this issue was plaguing users in 2016. Check your `build.gradle` and ensure you are using most recent libs, which at the time of writing this answer is `10.2.1`

Comment: When I try to update the libraries to 10.2.1 it always says: Failed to resolve ...

Comment: Now I get this Error Error:`A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing a similar problem and after some experimentation observed that the `FirebaseUI Version <-> Firebase/Play Services Version` should match as mentioned in https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android. However per the chart the best matching combination that worked for me was `0.6.2 (FirebaseUI Version) <-> (Firebase/Play Services Version)  9.8.0`.